# Is the very first time a query of an application run expected to be slower than successive executions due to plan compiliation?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

As the question states - is it to be expected that on the very first time a given query is executed, that the response time will be slower than subsequent requests, due to plan compilation?

Also, the more complex a plan is, the longer this first request will be?  I realize there are many other things that could be involved, but in general, this first request will be slower?

Comment: Probably more likely that pumping data into memory the first time it is requested is taking a lot more time than plan compilation. While there are exceptions, I've rarely seen plan compilation be an overwhelming performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only. Assuming a server start, there is no cached data - so everything hits the (slow) disc. Once you rerun, not only does the query optimizer not have to run again - there also is a lot of data already in cache.